# Opening Multiple Text files with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, text

Hi all I am stuck with a small error with my VBA code. I want to open multiple text files and parse it to my excel. I am able to select multiple files but only one file gets parsed I am not sure why can someone please help me with this.

```
Sub lithium()
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
Dim PathInit As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Long
 Dim z As Long, filecount As Long
' Opening the txt file

  Dim myTxt
  myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files,*.txt", , , , True)

On Error Resume Next
filecount = UBound(myTxt)
On Error GoTo 0

If filecount = 0 Then MsgBox "No text file selected. Exiting now.", _
vbExclamation: Exit Sub

 For n = LBound(myTxt) To filecount
Open myTxt(n) For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

'Saving the entire value of the text file into the array. every element in the array in the entire row of the txt file

    '~~> Do stuffs here for text parsing...



 Dim strRow1() As String
 Dim strRow2() As String
 Dim strRow3() As String
 Dim strRow4() As String
 Dim strRow5() As String
 Dim strRow6() As String
 Dim nCount As Integer
' Dim row_number As Integer
 'row_number = 1
 nCount = 1
 Dim nRowLenth As Integer
 nRowLenth = UBound(strData) - LBound(strData) ' Length of the total data array
 j = 3

For i = 5 To nRowLenth


    If nCount Mod 2 <> 0 Then

        strRow1() = Split(strData(i), ";")
        strRow2() = Split(strData(i + 1), ";")
        strRow3() = Split(strData(i + 2), ";")
        strRow4() = Split(strData(i + 3), ";")
        strRow5() = Split(strData(i + 4), ";")
        strRow6() = Split(strData(i + 5), ";")




          Cells(j, 1).Value = strRow1(0)
          Cells(j, 2).Value = Mid(strRow1(2), 3, Len(strRow1(2)))
          Cells(j, 3).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow2(2), 3, Len(strRow2(2))))
          Cells(j, 4).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow3(2), 3, Len(strRow3(2))))
          Cells(j, 5).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow4(2), 3, Len(strRow4(2))))
          Cells(j, 6).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow5(2), 3, Len(strRow5(2))))
          Cells(j, 7).Value = Mid(strRow6(2), 3, Len(strRow6(2)))

        If i + 5 = nRowLenth Then
            Exit For
        Else
            i = i + 5

        End If
    End If

    If nCount Mod 2 = 0 Then

        strRow1() = Split(strData(i), ";")
        strRow2() = Split(strData(i + 1), ";")
        strRow3() = Split(strData(i + 2), ";")
        Cells(j, 1).Value = strRow1(0)
        Cells(j, 2).Value = "#N/A"
        Cells(j, 3).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow1(2), 3, Len(strRow1(2))))
        Cells(j, 4).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow2(2), 3, Len(strRow2(2))))
        Cells(j, 5).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(strRow3(2), 3, Len(strRow3(2))))
        Cells(j, 6).Value = "#N/A"
        Cells(j, 7).Value = "#N/A"

        If i + 2 = nRowLenth Then
            Exit For
        Else
            i = i + 2

        End If
    End If

 j = j + 1
  nCount = nCount + 1
Next i

'time transformation

Dim l As Long
Dim LR As Long
k = 3
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For l = 3 To LR

 Range("H" & k).Value = Val(Left(Right(Range("A" & l).Value, 10), 2)) + Val(Right(Left(Right(Range("A" & l).Value, 10), 5), 2)) / 60 + Val(Right(Right(Range("A" & l).Value, 10), 4)) / 3600

  k = k + 1

 Next l
 Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: The line `strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)` saves the file into an array. Where do you write that array to your excel file? It looks to me as if you just overwrite the array with each new file.

Comment: yes i write the array to an excel file

Comment: Please show us the code where you write that array into the excel file

Comment: how do we not overwrite and have the data from all the text files and parse it inot the excel worksheet?

Comment: I have posted the code where I parse the array and write that to excel

Comment: "j" is set to 3 for each file, right? You need to define `j = 3` before the very first loop for the files if I am not mistaken. Right now you write each input file into the same cells in your destination excel file, and so you only ever see the last file written.

Comment: thanks for the response. by define you mean declare j right? I am new to this so a little bit tricky i find this

Comment: Don't worry and take your time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Delete the following line from your code

```
j = 3
```

Add this line to the top (declarations)

```
Dim j As Integer
j = 3
```